# How to prove this inequality for operator and function

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

How to prove this?

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|(Tf)_k|^2\leq ||T||^2||f||^2$

where $T$ is an operator and a function $f$. $(Tf)_k$ is the $k$-th coordinate of *Tf*.

Should this involve Cauchy-Schwarz or the inner product $< ,>$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The term on the left is 
$$
     \|Tf \|^2
=    \left\|T \frac{f}{\|f\|} \right\|^2 \|f\|^2
\leq \sup\left\{ \left\|T g \right\| \mid \|g\|=1\right\}^2 \|f\|^2
=    \|T\|^2 \|f\|^2
$$

Comment: Half an answer, still worth +1!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in a nutshell, *sans* my typical long-windedness;  note that, to make this one fly, Wilbur, we need to assume we are dealing with a separable Hilbert space, so we can invoke a countable orthonormal basis $\mathbf e_k$.  Also, I am obviously assuming that $(Tf)_k = \langle \mathbf e_k, Tf \rangle$.

1.)  $Tf = \sum_1^\infty \langle \mathbf e_j, Tf \rangle \mathbf e_j; \tag{1}$

2.)  $\langle Tf, Tf \rangle = \langle \sum_1^\infty \langle \mathbf e_j, Tf \rangle \mathbf e_j, \sum_1^\infty \langle  \mathbf e_k, Tf \rangle \mathbf e_k \rangle = \sum_{j, k = 1}^{j, k = \infty} \langle \mathbf e_j, \mathbf e_k \rangle \overline{\langle \mathbf e_j, Tf \rangle} \langle \mathbf e_k, Tf \rangle$
$= \sum_{j, k = 1}^{j, k = \infty} \delta _{jk} \overline{\langle \mathbf e_j, Tf \rangle} \langle \mathbf e_k, Tf \rangle = \sum_1^\infty \overline{\langle \mathbf e_k, Tf \rangle} \langle \mathbf e_k, Tf \rangle = \sum_1^\infty  \vert (Tf)_k \vert^2; \tag{2}$

3.)  Also, $\vert \langle Tf, Tf \rangle \vert \le \Vert Tf \Vert^2$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, and $\Vert Tf \Vert \le \Vert T \Vert \Vert f \Vert$, so $\vert \langle Tf, Tf \rangle \vert  \le \Vert T \Vert^2 \Vert f \Vert^2; \tag{3}$

Finally, combining (2) and (3) we have

4.)  $\sum_1^\infty \vert (Tf)_k \vert^2 \le \Vert T \Vert ^2 \Vert f \Vert^2, \tag{4}$

as was to be shown.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Above still needs some editing.  Begging your patience!

Comment: OK, edits all done!  (At least for the time being!)